# How do I have jquery preserve my escaped HTML string during selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an escaped HTML string, that when selected by jQuery unescapes my escaped string with a vulnerability for running scripts.  See this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/x751u2gq/2/

```
<div id="banner-message">
<button>Inject Alert Message</button>
<span id="myspan" 
name="&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert(String.fromCharCode(84, 11, 
107, 101, 110, 46))&lt;/script&gt;"></span>
</div>

button.on("click", function(){
banner.addClass("alt");
span = $("#myspan").attr("name");
$("#myspan").html(span);
})
```

How do I get jQuery to select the string as is, e.g. "</script><script>alert(String.fromCharCode(84, 11, 
107, 101, 110, 46))</script>"

Comment: The name of the element is actually an escaped tag?  Thats totally whack.

Comment: @Programnik that's just for illustrative purposes but a value like that is being passed from the server escaped and in the process is unescaped